# Is there a great WYSIWYG html editor component that had Drag n' Drop *like* the Google Waves editor?

Tags: javascript, html, google-gears

Is there a component out there that can be used that provides some of the 
great capabilities that the Google Waves editor provides (or Google Docs editor)? 
If it only works on a certain browser, that is fine. If it is part
of GWT or some other framework, that is fine. I know that this will probably require Google Gears. I would prefer just a javascript library.

It must/should have:

- Drag and Drop of images or files into
  the area
- The ability to have toggle for sections that were changes
  (version history)
- Basic support for PRE, Links, OL, LI. (Stack overflow editor, is close)
- It must have auto-save support
- It must have a sane API and system for uploading/communicating with server

It does not need:

- Spell check
- Real-time character by character
  collaboration
- Full playback of editor history

I have seen FCKEditor and tinyMce. These editors are way too clunky and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/GoogleWavePoweredByGWT.html), Google Wave uses GWT, so you should be able to get those effects using GWT.

For direct confirmation of this, watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWMVzhXwh-I), where between 40 and 45 seconds in, a Google employee says about the Google Wave web client "it was built with the Google Web Toolkit".

(See also [this search for "wave" and "gwt"](http://www.google.com/search?&q=wave+gwt))

Comment: can anyone confirm that, however?

Answer (score 0):

The drag and drop would require Gears as mentioned in the wave presentation, but they are working on getting an html 5 drag and drop api accepted. I don't know of any good solution to do all the other things. I know there are some simple rich text editors that can be used as plugins to mediawiki, so those combined could give you most of that functionality.